# MOQ - verify method with parameter executed regardless of the parameter used

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method which inside calls another method.

This method has only one signature, for example:

```
 Koko(ComplexType isKoko)
```

I want to verify that this method executed without checking the instance of the parameter and doing something like this:

```
 It check_description = () => mockKoko.Verify(x => x.Koko(anything), Times.Once());
```

I searched the forum and Google and couldn't find an answer.

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `It.IsAny<ComplexType>()`:

```
check_description = () => mockKoko.Verify(x => x.Koko(It.IsAny<ComplexType>()), Times.Once());
```

Answer (score 5):

```cs
mock.Verify(m => m.MethodToCheckIfCalled(It.Is<IUserDTO>(x =>  x.LastName == "3" & x.FirstName == "2")));
```